# String splitting consecutive duplicate charcter

Tags: c#, string, split

I have the following string:

```
/A//B/C//D
```

I need to get the following array of strings when splitting:

```
A
/B
C
/D
```

I have tried the following code but it seems that simply splitting by ('/') will omit the occurrence of any '/' in the string.

```
mystring.split('/');
```

Is there a way that i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
var input = "/A//B/C//D";
var result = Regex.Split(input, "(?<!/)/");
```

This will split the string by any `/` character not preceeded by another `/` character. Unfortunately, you will get an empty string for the first element of the result array. If this is a problem you can simply use a little bit of Linq to filter it out:

```
var result = Regex.Split(input, "(?<!/)/").Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Or

```
var result = Regex.Split(input, "(?<!/)/").Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sArray = s.Replace("//", "~").Replace("/", "`").Replace("~", "`/").Split("`");
```

[Edit]

Or use a regex :)